# django ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a query to the Preferences table I have in django, but whenever I try to do a lookup to find a users entry, it just gives me this error.

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'jason'

The lookup I'm doing is this.

> Preferences.objects.filter(customer='jason')

I can do this though which is odd.

> Preferences.objects.all()

And I retrieve the query set of the one object I want.
When I ask

> Preferences.objects.all()[0].customer

And here I do retrieve the string 'Jason'. Can you explain what's going wrong either in my query or in the code? Any help would be appreciated and I can give other parts of code if needed!

```
#models.py 
class Preferences(models.Model):
customer = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
ebay_token = models.TextField(max_length=1024)
app_id = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='asdf', editable=False)
dev_id = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='1234', editable=False)
cert_id = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='1234', editable=False)

#this might need to be correct. I'm not sure if the user should have this much control over markup
markup = models.FloatField(max_length=3, validators=[MaxValueValidator(50, message='Can\'t be this high!'), MinValueValidator(1, message='Can\'t be this low!')])
seller_location = models.CharField(max_length=256)
#the ebay site number might need editing
ebay_site_number = models.IntegerField()
quantity = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1, message='Must be atleast 1'), MaxValueValidator(10, message='Must be equal to or smaller than 10')])

#this will def need fixing here
fullfillment_policy = models.CharField(max_length=64)
payment_policy = models.CharField(max_length=64)
return_policy = models.CharField(max_length=64)

#default weight
default_weight = models.IntegerField(help_text='Default weight for item in pounds', default=15, validators=[MinValueValidator(1, message='Must be atleast 1 pound'), MaxValueValidator(500, message='Must be equal to or less than 500')])
paypalEmailAddress = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='user@gmail.com')


def __str__(self):
    return "{} | Preferences".format(self.customer.username)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`models.OneToOneField` expects an `id` for pk or a `User` object.

Try

```
Preferences.objects.filter(customer__name='Jason')
```

or change the `__name` part to  whatever the field is in your `User` model.

Comment: To ignore case use: `Preferences.objects.filter(customer__username__iexact='Jason')`